# Reading beyond the end of an istringstream's string.

Tags: c++, input, error-handling

As a beginner programmer I'm trying to understand everything from my book, but I'm having some problems in understanding this piece of code that I've written to see its behaviour.

Suppose I want to read data into a string, clean those data and then putting the "cleaned-up" data's into an istringstream so that I can read it again :

```
string line; 
getline(cin, line); 

// clean up data....

istringstream ss(line);
vector<string> vs; 
for (string word; ss >> word; )
    vs.push_back(word);
```

Now, by writing this code I remembered about a quote from my book that says :

> If you try to read beyond the end of an istringstream's string, it will go in eof() state.

So I tried to test with two `if` conditions the stream after the `for loop` and I got that it is both in **eof() state** and in **fail() state**. Is it possible for a stream to be in both of these states ?  Why am I getting this result ? How can I properly find the real state of a stream after input operations ? I've just started learning about I/O streams and I'm having some problems. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible for your stream to be both in eof and failed state. This happens when you try reading past the end of the stream. This is the proper state of the stream after you have finished reading everything from it, and tested that there's nothing left.

This is precisely what your loop does, and that is absolutely OK to do so. When your stream is positioned past its last character, the eof flag is not yet set. It would get set as soon as you try reading some more. This is by design. Once you do read some more, both eof and failed flags get set, which leads to loop termination, as expected.

Comment: After a little pause from programming I came back and restarted by studying files better, but I still have troubles in understanding a thing, is it possible to trigger just the eof flag ? My question rises from a problem that I'm trying to solve within another question here : [link] (stackoverflow.com/questions/37550979/…)

Comment: @PieroBorrelli `eof` flag is always set together with the fail flag: ["Operations that attempt to read at the End-of-File fail, and thus both the `eofbit` and the `failbit` end up set."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/)

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the stream state through `operator bool`; now this returns `!this.fail()` which is `true` if `failbit` or `badbit` is set, not `eofbit`.

When you reach EOF (that is reading past the end of the stream), the [behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction) of `>>` and `<<` is to set `eofbit` *and* `failbit`.

> How can I properly find the real state of a stream after input operations ?

You are already doing it the proper way, namely through `operator bool` - what you may want to do to understand it even further is [looking up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) `iostate`-s and the its accessors.